# Regex to remove (whatever_inside) IFF and only IFF if there is no spacing inside the brackets

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove something like `(Q.5)` or  `(5.)` or `(Question5)`. I have the regex pattern for it but the thing is that It is removing things outside the brackets too.

I have used `\((\S+)\)|((\s|\n)\S\s*\.\s*)` but it is converting

```
(d)  Q 2.3 5.6 hello. J.E.E (Q.4)  (Q4) (Q4.)
```

To

```
Q 3 6 hello. E.E
```

but the output I expect is

```
Q 2.3 5.6 hello. J.E.E
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `(...)` are balance and unescaped, you may use this regex with a *negated character class* for search:

```
\s*\([^)\s]*\)\s*
```

and replace with empty string.

**Code:**

```sh
>>> import re
>>> s = '(d)  Q 2.3 5.6 hello. J.E.E (Q.4)  (Q4) (Q4.)'
>>> print (re.sub(r'\s*\([^)\s]*\)\s*', '', s))
Q 2.3 5.6 hello. J.E.E
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/69ODDH/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `\(`: Match opening `(`
- `[^)\s]*`: Negated character class to match 0 or more of any character that is not `)` and not a whitespace
- `\)`: Match closing `)`
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces